# Como puedo contar los valores de un array de json y listarlos con html?

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo el siguiente json "archivos", solo me interesa contar los tipodescrip para hacer una lista con ellos para saber cuantos tipos tengo

estoy usando angular para construir mis funciones

se aceptan sugerencias

```
{
    "archivos": [
        {
            "nombre": "eir 2018, 1799.pdf",
            "id": "1595146",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "COVE"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "SIM38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585738",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Pedimento"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "ORD38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585739",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Pedimento Aduanal"
        },        
        {
            "nombre": "h3412724.pdf",
            "id": "1591453",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "h3412724.xml",
            "id": "1591454",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "xml2.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "20180427145021682O.xml",
            "id": "1572837",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.xml",
            "mime": "xml2.png",
            "tipodescrip": "COVE"
        }
    ]
}
```

asi obtengo los archivos

```
  var oficina = localStorage.getItem("numoficina");
    var vgget = globales[urlgetarchivos][oficina];
    $http({
        url: vgget,
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            referencia: ref
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'dataType': 'json'
        }
    })
   .success(function (response) {

       console.log(response.archivos);

       var r = response.archivos;

       console.log(r);

       $scope.itemsarchivo = r;


   }).catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
       //alert("Error: " + error);
   });
```

quisiera crear un  para poner dentro de cada uno el nombre de tipo de archivo y adentro el path del archivo para consultarlo

agradezco el apoyo

Comment: Que version de angular estas usando?

Comment: estoy usando  AngularJS v1.5.3 @TheVicious

Comment: aun tienes problema?

Comment: Sii aun no lo gro generar mi lista desplegable ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahi te va mi sugerencia:

```js
var data = {
    "archivos": [
        {
            "nombre": "eir 2018, 1799.pdf",
            "id": "1595146",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "COVE"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "SIM38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585738",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Pedimento"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "ORD38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585739",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Pedimento Aduanal"
        },        
        {
            "nombre": "h3412724.pdf",
            "id": "1591453",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "h3412724.xml",
            "id": "1591454",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "xml2.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "20180427145021682O.xml",
            "id": "1572837",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.xml",
            "mime": "xml2.png",
            "tipodescrip": "COVE"
        }
    ]
}
var tiposdescrip = [];
data.archivos.forEach(function(archivo) {  
  if(tiposdescrip.indexOf(archivo.tipodescrip) == -1) {
    tiposdescrip.push(archivo.tipodescrip);
    var ul = document.getElementById("lista");
     var li = document.createElement("li");
     li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(archivo.tipodescrip));
     ul.appendChild(li);
  }
});
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total: " + tiposdescrip.length;
```

```html
<p id="total"></p>
<ul id="lista"></ul>
```

Comment: Gracias funciona de maravilla pero estoy trabajando con angular olvide comentar ese detalle

Answer (score 0):

No se si entiendo muy bien tu pregunta pero espero que te sirva, te recomendaría para hacer un listado de `items` a un archivo `JSON` que ya tienes establecido, una petición `get` de la siguiente manera.

**data.json**

```
{
    "archivos": [
        {
            "nombre": "eir 2018, 1799.pdf",
            "id": "1595146",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "COVE"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "SIM38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585738",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Pedimento"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "ORD38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585739",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Pedimento Aduanal"
        },        
        {
            "nombre": "h3412724.pdf",
            "id": "1591453",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "h3412724.xml",
            "id": "1591454",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.pdf",
            "mime": "xml2.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "20180427145021682O.xml",
            "id": "1572837",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//1bd4c703-08f4-470a-80b6-0f48d0c5a547.xml",
            "mime": "xml2.png",
            "tipodescrip": "COVE"
        }
    ]
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    //vamos a hacer uso de $http para obtener los datos
    $http.get('data.json').then(function (res) {
    //enviamos los datos a la vista con el objeto $scope
        $scope.datos = res.data.archivos;
    }, function(res){
        console.log('Fallo la busqueda');
    });

 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
    <select ng-model="selectName">
        <option ng-repeat="t in datos" value="{{ t.id }}">{{ t.tipodescrip }}</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="selectPath">
        <option ng-repeat="p in datos" value="{{ p.id }}">{{ p.path }}</option>
    </select>
</body>

</html>
```

PD: Para que el código te sirva tienes que llamar la ruta donde se encuentra este `JSON`, quedo atento  a cualquier pregunta.

Comment: el webservice no admite el metodo get solo admite post  como se muestra en el ejemplo de arriva

Comment: @emanuelle bueno no sabia ese dato.